# Images not loading in Chrome when changing img src via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, image, src

I'm pulling album art from the Deezer API via AJAX for a Chrome extension I'm making however some of the images don't render. I'm fetching the album art for ~30 tracks and some display but some don't.

The AJAX request completes and I receive the image url which I then add to the page with the following (The Date.getTime() was something I read to avoid caching):

```
var img = $("<img />");
img.attr('src', imageSrc + "?" + new Date().getTime());
$(_this.dom).find(".card-image").html(img);
```

If I inspect the page, the  src is set correctly to http://cdn-images.deezer.com/images/cover/7f3d5b5c3c0358e3edc58ee8d9f6cabb/250x250-000000-80-0-0.jpg?1438639441322 for example but the  element itself has a height of 0 and nothing is displayed.

If I open the image file in a new tab, it's displayed correctly so there isn't a problem with the link.

Any ideas? This is driving me slowly insane.

There's a screenshot here which shows the problem I'm having: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HaTxP.png)

Comment: Have you tried using a browser inspector (like webkit's) to manually size the image? If you can supply a link, or even a js fiddle, I'll look into it for you.

Comment: I had a similar issue once, where I was appending a number of new images and then re-sizing them once they were added. The issue was a race condition, so I wrapped my re-size in `$(window).load(function(e) {});` which fixed the issue. Not sure if this comment will be helpful, however just sounds like a very similar problem.

Comment: @Jackson Yes, I've specified a height for the image using the chrome dev tools but it's still blank. Really strange.

The chrome extension is here, just drag it into chrome://extensions

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwGS92F7YA7rR3RiWUt5LUZLdU0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @ings0c It's definitely something with the image format on *some* images. I took one of the "broken" images, converted it to base64, put the base64 value in as the src, and the image worked. The opposite is also true, I took the src of a broken image and put it as the source for the image on google.com and it won't show. It sounds like your source for images may be compiling them faulty / sending you faulty return headers.

Comment: @Jackson Awesome, thanks for looking into it. I'll try and pull the images from somewhere else and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: @Jackson aaaargh. I've just changed it to use the Last.FM API instead of Deezer but the problem is still there.

Surely both APIs aren't sending faulty headers? Would you mind taking a look? I've repackaged the extension with the changes - https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwGS92F7YA7raXg3RzhRNzZsV2s/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @ings0c Now you have the default image in place so I can't see the actual source img so I'm not of much help on this version. I suggest you try your code as a website just to test the image loading. This error could possibly be an issue with the extension renderer.